# closeWebView after 5 seconds - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to make a button in flutter to open an URL inside the app and close it after 5 seconds, and then going back to the app.

```
const url = 'https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher';
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _launchInBrowser(url);
          Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
            closeWebView();
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      ),
```

This is the function to open the URL inside the app:

```
Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(
      url,
      forceSafariVC: true,
      forceWebView: false,
      headers: <String, String>{'header_key': 'header_value'},
    );
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

The URL is opening fine, however it's not closing after 5 seconds. What function should I use to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The timer keeps on running for the duration repeatedly and that may be the reason it's not closing. Try to close the timer after first run using the cancel() method.